# Blender appears zoomed in, Windows 10

Tags: windows

Having this problem since I updated to W10 from W7. The whole blender window appears zoomed in. See:

[image: Blender appears zoomed in]

*The window is minimized just for the screenshot*

You can see on the edges the effect of the zoom. This is only solved by using Alt + F11  to turn it up to full screen, where there's no such zoom effect.

What is causing this and how can I solve it? I've tried compatibility modes, running as admin, reinstalling, and installing old versions. NOTHING solves this.

EDIT: I should also mention that it's only the display of the window that's zoomed, because technically the buttons and stuff are at the right place. You can see this with my mouse:

[image]

So it's only the appearance that is offset with the zoom effect.

PC Specs:

Pentium G4560 3.5ghz

8 GB DDR4 RAM

Intel HD 610

Comment: @MrZak Are you kidding me? xD I thought I shouldn't even have mentioned such an obvious thing. It's the same if maximized. I just minimized the window so that it would appear better in the screenshot. :P Sorry

Comment: Any thing should be mentioned when troubleshooting. Now it's more clear. I would include the screenshot of maximized to show exactly that. This might be another little problem of win 10. What graphic card do you have? I saw only freezing when minimizing bug, try doing what is proposed in [this report](https://developer.blender.org/T50856) to see if this is related to Blender at all.

Comment: @MrZak I don't have a dedicated GPU, it's the internal Intel HD 610. From the link you gave above, there's a solution to this problem, which is putting the opengl32.dll file into the Blender folder. That solves the problem, but Blender becomes really really slow and buggy.

Comment: The solution with OpenGL32.dll is only for testing; it checks whether your problem is related to the graphic drivers, and if it works correct now then yes, it is related. Try updating them / rolling back, if not working then it might be necessary to find another GPU hardware

Comment: What resolution are you running?  Did you change hardware at the same time you upgraded OS?  Did you "upgrade" to Win10 or did you do a fresh install?

Comment: @bertmoog 1920x1080. Yes, I changed my mb, proc and ram when I upgraded to W10. And I did a fresh install, by formatting my C drive which had W7 on it (it wasn't booting with my new mb) and installing W10 over it.

Comment: THEY FIXED IT IN THE NEW GRAPHICS DRIVER UPDATE!!!!! YAY!!!!!!!!!!

_(sorry for all caps, I'm REALLY happy and overjoyed)_