# Blender - 2.78c - Can't see menus

Tags: interface, error

I have started blender and can't see my menus. Any suggestions on how to fix?

As can be seen from the attached image I cant get the top and bottom menu's.

Uninstalled and re-installed and did not fix.

[image]

Comment: Resizing, mimizing and de-minimizing the window doesn't lead to any improvement?

Comment: Hi Carlo. Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and no improvement.

Comment: Try updating graphic drivers, see in comments https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84622/blender-appears-zoomed-in-windows-10

Comment: hi Mr Zak thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on any main icon panel (the first one) and choose **Info**.

[image]

Comment: Hi LeoNas - thanks for your response. I am a bit confused by your answer. Can you elaborate on how I can use that to fix the issue?

Comment: All the panels have a menu. Click the icon and choose **Info** as showing the images above.