# Can't access some areas in blender

Tags: interface

i don't know how i got this problem but my blender has a problem which doesn't allow me to see or use the top part (menu bar by default) and the bottom part of blender; i tried restarting my computer and also reinstalling blender but i still have the same problem. need help; below is the link of image of my blender looks now.

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAx1D.jpg

Comment: Upload the image to imgur.com or something similar - and be glad people can't just access files on your computer directly! ;)

Comment: Please search before posting, this has been asked countless times before https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84622/blender-appears-zoomed-in-windows-10

Comment: oh sorry i didn't search it right way so never got it. i will delete this post soon; thanks everyone for reply.